# Are all immutable objects singleton instances?

Tags: immutability

Are all immutable objects singleton instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

[Immutable objects](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/) are unchangeable, the normal practice for these is to pass (inject) all required values via the constructor (i.e. they are specified when the object is instantiated), these are then externally unchangeable for the lifetime of the object.

[Singleton objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) are when there is a single instance, that instance could be immutable but seldom is.

Comment: singleton instance is always immutable right?

Comment: @MaheshJ No. A singleton is not immutable. There will only ever be one instance of a singleton no matter how many times you access it - it gets instantiated the first time you access it and then lives forever, so the instance doesn't change **but it isn't immutable**.